# Memory usage of an infinitely looping shell script

Tags: shell-script, memory

So, I have a shell script for updating a MySQL database that looks something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
mysql -h "localhost" -u "root" "-p********" "database" < "update.sql"
sleep 5
sh $0
```

It sleeps for 5 seconds and then the `sh $0` reruns the script infinitely, without my intervention. However, my question is about memory:

I am relatively new to shell scripts, but is the memory slowly piling up in a loop like this? Does the remote server recycle the memory, or will the script eventually reach a cut-off? (Or, will it crash from a memory leak?)

Comment: `sh $0` forks a new shell and runs your command, which in turn forks another shell and runs your command. It is this that is piling up the memory usage. You can get around this by `exec`. Prefix your `sh $0` with `exec` and the present shell will be terminated, freeing the memory use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a loop, but recursion and the memory increases linear over the time, which is what you don't want.

If you want a loop with constant memory usage, you can do it this way:

```
#!/bin/sh
while 1; do
  mysql -h "localhost" -u "root" "-p********" "database" < "update.sql"
  sleep 5
done
```

Comment: He could also retain his original script and utilize `exec`.

Comment: @Drav Sloan Sure. Thanks for adding this. But while loop is (I think) easier to understand and you will avoid re-exec.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the shell. Some do tail call optimization, others don't. You can test this easily by running `SHELL -c 'ps $$'`. If `ps` sees itself, the shell has executed the last command in the same process. If `ps` sees the shell, the shell runs the last command in a subprocess, as it does for commands that aren't the last one.

```
$ for s in dash bash mksh ksh zsh; do echo -n "$s "; $s -c 'ps -o comm= $$'; done 
dash dash
bash ps
mksh mksh
ksh ps
zsh ps
```

So bash, ksh and zsh do tail call optimization, dash and mksh don't.

Tail call optimization can only be done for the very last command in a script. For example, if there's an active trap, it isn't a tail call, since the shell needs to stay behind in case the trap is triggered.

You can force a tail call by putting `exec` in front of the command. The `exec` builtin executes the specified command in the same process. Further commands in the script won't be executed since the shell is gone.

Recursion isn't idiomatic in shell scripts. It would be more idiomatic to use a loop:

```
#!/bin/sh
while true; do
  mysql -h "localhost" -u "root" "-p********" "database" < "update.sql"
  sleep 5
done
```

or, if you want the script to exit if the `sleep` command is killed by a signal:

```
#!/bin/sh
while
  mysql -h "localhost" -u "root" "-p********" "database" < "update.sql"
  sleep 5
do
  :
done
```

or, if you want the script to exit if `mysql` fails:

```
#!/bin/sh
while
  mysql -h "localhost" -u "root" "-p********" "database" < "update.sql"
do
  sleep 5
done
```